# Show that for tree T $2\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(x,v) \lt \sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(y,v)+\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(z,v)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let T be a tree and x a vertex that is not a leaf. Also let $y,z \in N(x)$, meaning that y and z are connected to x by an edge.
Prove that: 
$$2\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(x,v) \lt \sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(y,v)+\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(z,v)$$

My approach was: using the fact that x is not a leaf, we get
$$2\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(x,v) \lt 2V(T)diam(T)$$
where diam(T) is the maximum distance between two vertices.
Then i used the triangle inequality to get:
$$\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(y,v)+\sum_{v \in V(T)}dist(z,v) = \sum_{v \in V(T)}(dist(y,v)+dist(v,z)) \ge V(T)dist(y,z)=2V(T)$$ (Last equality is due to the fact that T is a tree so dist(y,z)=2).
Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: I would take a different approach. Root $T$ at $x$. Show that if $v$ is in the subtree rooted at $y$, then

$$\operatorname{dist}(z,v)-1=\operatorname{dist}(x,v)=\operatorname{dist}(y,v)+1\;,$$

and hence

$$2\operatorname{dist}(x,v)=\operatorname{dist}(y,v)+\operatorname{dist}(z,v)\;.$$

Prove a similar result for vertices $v$ in the subtree rooted at $z$. Finally, show that if $u$ is any other neighbor of $x$, and $v$ is in the subtree rooted at $u$, then

$$\operatorname{dist}(y,v)=\operatorname{dist}(z,v)=\operatorname{dist}(x,v)+1\;.$$